# Java Convert IP+Port to Long and Back

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

I'm trying to store an ipaddress and port inside of a Long. My code below works for ports with a value less than 255, but does not work with anything more.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String first = "192.168.1.2:84";
        String second = "255.255.255.255:65535";

        long ip1 = ipToLong(first);
        System.out.println("iptoLong  : " + ip1);

        System.out.println("longToIp  : " + longToIp(ip1));

        System.out.println();

        ip1 = ipToLong(second);
        System.out.println("iptoLong  : " + ip1);

        System.out.println("longToIp  : " + longToIp(ip1));

    }

    public static long ipToLong(String ipAddress) {
        int port = Integer.parseInt(ipAddress.substring(ipAddress.indexOf(":") + 1, ipAddress.length()));
        ipAddress = ipAddress.replace(":", "").replace(""+port, "");

        String[] ip = ipAddress.split("\\.");

        long result = 0;
        result |= Long.parseLong(ip[0]) << 40;
        result |= Long.parseLong(ip[1]) << 32;
        result |= Long.parseLong(ip[2]) << 24;
        result |= Long.parseLong(ip[3]) << 16;

        result |= port << 8;
        result |= port;

        return result;
    }

    public static String longToIp(long i) {
        long port  = ((i >> 8) & 0xFF) | (i & 0xFF);

        return ((i >> 40) & 0xFF) +
                   "." + ((i >> 32) & 0xFF) +
                   "." + ((i >> 24) & 0xFF) +
                   "." + ((i >> 16) & 0xFF) +
                   ":" + port;

    }
}
```

Here is what that code outputs:

```
iptoLong  : 211827803968596
longToIp  : 192.168.1.2:84

iptoLong  : 281474976710655
longToIp  : 255.255.255.255:255
```

As you can see in the second example it prints 255 instead of 65535.

Here is an ideone link to the snippet: http://ideone.com/rWo7qJ

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're both encoding and decoding the port wrong.

For encoding you're doing:

```
result |= port << 8;
result |= port;
```

Assuming that your port is 0xfeff, what you're doing is:

```
result |= 0xfeff00;
result |= 0x00feff;
```

That (the first line) doesn't do something useful and will overwrite the least significant byte from the ip address. But that's not what is causing your problem - you would need to use different numbers like `1.2.3.4:65534` to see that problem in action.

What you should be doing is:

```
result |= port & 0xFFFF;
```

(The `& 0xFFFF` part is to protect your code against negative numbers and numbers  65535 since they would otherwise overwrite the IP#)

To decode, you're doing:

```
long port  = ((i >> 8) & 0xFF) | (i & 0xFF);
```

Now assume that the lowest 16 bits of the `long` contains `0xFFFF`, then your code does:

```
long port = ((0xFFFF >> 8) & 0xFF) | (0xFFF & 0xFF)
          =  0xFF                  | 0xFF
          =  0xFF;
```

instead you expected `0xFFFF`. Do instead:

```
long port = (i & 0xFFFF);
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because you shift everything by 8 bits. The highest number possible in 8 bits is 255 (=11111111). If you want to store a number higher than 255 you will have to shift more than 8 bits.
255=11111111=8bits,
65535=1111111111111111=16bits.
That means you will have to shift everything an additional 8bits:

```
long result = 0;
result |= Long.parseLong(ip[0]) << 48;
result |= Long.parseLong(ip[1]) << 40;
result |= Long.parseLong(ip[2]) << 32;
result |= Long.parseLong(ip[3]) << 24;

result |= port << 16;
```

Next, why do you get the port and the ip-address like:

```
int port = Integer.parseInt(ipAddress.substring(ipAddress.indexOf(":") + 1, ipAddress.length()));
ipAddress = ipAddress.replace(":", "").replace(""+port, "");
```

when you could also have chosen to do:

```
String[] ipadressandport = ipAddress.split(":");
int port = Integer.parseInt(ipaddressandport[1]);
String[] ip = ipaddressandport[0].split("\\.");
```

which looks a lot cleaner and is also faster.